# Why did the Rosen corporation want to discredit the Voight-Kampff test?

Tags: do-androids-dream-of-electric-sheep

In Philip K. Dick's *Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep?*, why did the Rosen corporation want to discredit the Voight-Kampff test? If the new Nexus 6 types were to be so good and human-like that they pass the empathy test, then wouldn't the pressure be on the Rosen corporation to stop the Nexus 6 production? I would imagine that the company would be glad if they failed the test so that escaped androids can still be easily detected and retired. Were they trying to show how good their Nexus 6 are?

Comment: The VK test may not be a definite yes/no thing. There's a score - over this score you're a replicant, under that score you're human. Neither ever scores close to the borderline. But if the Nexus 6 can get scores close enough to human values that there is doubt, then discrediting the VK test (even a bit) means it can't be used reliably, which helps the corporation.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that it was a way to get a hold on Bryant.
They made him make a mess of the test and then used that to get him to be cooperative.